# If value is between ranges then answer is a specific number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

### [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eep3HKqbjuuRhozqJs-2FNN0lGWnWr-rIxeFVeuMqII/edit#gid=850110546)

I have a time sheet with start time, end time, and duration. The fee is based off the duration.

ie.
0-60min equals $100
61-75min equals $125
76-90min equals $150

I'm trying to figure out a way for it to automatically produce the fee off the duration cell.

Thank you for any help...very new to this,

I tried some IF/Then commands but it didn't seem to be the direction I need to go

---

### My attempt include images per request:

[image: This is the first sheet where the answer should display]

You can see the `=vlookup(F24,Fee!$A$2:$C$35,3,2)` gives $0 although a time of 276 (F24) should equal $475

[image: This is the Second sheet Fee! that data is being pulled from]

I hope this helps more... Thank you for your time and effort on this, it's very much appreciated and I'm learning a lot from you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `VLOOKUP` formula and a "rates" table that you can reference for your fees.

**Formula**

- `=vlookup(D2,$G$2:$I$4,3,1)`

  - where "D2" = minutes
  - where $G$2:$I$4 is the rates table

**Rates Table**

[image: Rates]

- Take the duration,

  - convert it to minutes, and
  - `VLOOKUP` to find the rate that matches the number of duration minutes.

---

**EXAMPLE**

[image: details]

- Duration:

  - Cell format: `duration`
  - formula: `=B2-A2`
- Minutes: `=hour(C2)*60+minute(C2)`
- Fee: `=vlookup(D2,$G$2:$I$4,3,1)`

Comment: Thank you! I think this will work perfectly.  I would like the rates table to be hidden on another sheet. I've named this sheet "Fee" I have everything working except for pulling the info from the other sheet.  Can you help with this also?  I really appreciate it!

=vlookup(D2,$G$2:$I$4,3,1). What does the 3,1 represent?

Comment: This is what I have so far: 
=vlookup(F24,Fee!$A$2:$C$35,3,1)

F24=Minutes
Fee=Second sheet with the Rates Table
Rates table range is A2:C35

Also, I found this on a webpage to explain part of my previous question:
The third value (3) is the column number of the data you want to return.
And the fourth value (1) is a logical value that specifies whether you want an exact or approximate match.

Comment: `This is what I have so far` That's 100% correct; you've got it under control. FWIW, someone _might_ ask: if the search is on Column A of the table, and the formula returns the value in Column C, then what is the purpose of column B? Two things: 1)  visually/intuitively, it makes the table easier to understand (the "From" fields have a context); 2) apart from the first row, the value in Column A = the value in Column B _from the previous row_ plus 1 (one); this can make the table easier to build.

Comment: it's not working as intended.  It's possible my question was not clear enough.   If 0-60 min = $100 the value in F24 could be 1min, 24min, 46 min or 60min and all of those entries would need to produce the value $100.   Will this formula work for that?

Comment: `Will this formula work for that?` Yes, I just tested it. Of course, when you say "1min", I assume that you mean the cell value = "1" and not "1min". I think the best thing is that you edit your question to include your sample data AND your calculations so that I can see just why `it's not working as intended`.

Comment: Tedinoz I was able to update the questions but the images are links, I don't know how to include them in the post like you did.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I used the exact same data and it works. But... an image has limited value because it doesn't let you evaluate the actual numbers . Please include a link to a sample spreadsheet so that I can dig into every value and understand their format and how they are calculated.

Comment: Tedinoz I've provided the link.  Appreciate all the help on this.

Comment: The spreadsheet formula skips a step from the answer. **Step#1 is OK**: "End time less start time" (e.g. Cell F24: `=E24-D24`). **Step#2 is skipped**: "Calculate the hours and minutes represented by the value in Cell F24": `=hour(F24)*60+minute(F24)`. You _can_ combine these: e.g. `=hour(E24-D24)*60+minute(E24-D24)` **and** format the cell as `Automatic`. That is what I have done on sheet: "Schneider2". Result: Fee=$225.

Comment: Successful! Appreciated greatly!